# Role based auth with IdentityServer4 and Keycloak 18

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, keycloak, identityserver4

After updating to keycloak 18, it expects id_token_hint that equals id_token and post_logout_redirect_uri on sign-out.
For .net client, our keycloak admins created new client scope - csharp-roles that converts roles to convenient view for .net and has setting that includes role claims to id_token.
We disabled this setting because  sign-out url is too large (id_token contained role claims) and sign-out works perfectly.
But after this changes We have an issue with login, IdentityServer during conversion token to Identity do not assign claims to it and I **guess** it happens because of IdentityServer for **MVC** project reads all claims from id_token, please see my setup below

```
 services
            .AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Login/Index";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Login/Logout";
                options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    OnValidatePrincipal = async cookieContext =>
                    {
                        var validator = cookieContext.HttpContext.RequestServices
                            .GetRequiredService<IPrincipalValidator>();
                        if (!await validator.ValidatePrincipal(cookieContext.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity))
                        {
                            //this will force Challenge redirect
                            cookieContext.RejectPrincipal();

                            //this will delete Identity Cookie, preventing issue with SessionController which relies on User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
                            await cookieContext.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults
                                .AuthenticationScheme);
                        }
                    }
                };
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.MetadataAddress = Configuration["oidc:Metadata"];
                options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.ClientId = Configuration["oidc:ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["oidc:ClientSecret"];
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                options.CallbackPath = "/oidc-callback";
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("email");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    RoleClaimType =
                        "roles", // using short name here, this is needed because we replace role claims (see code below, OnTicketReceived event)
                };
                options.SaveTokens = false; //all tokens are stored in session by TokenSourceHelper
                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = context =>
                    {
                        // pass current session ID to keycloak so it can use if for backchannel requests
                        if (context.HttpContext.Session != null)
                        {
                            var sessionId = context.HttpContext.Session.GetUniqueSessionId();
                            context.TokenEndpointRequest.Parameters.Add(
                                TokenSourceHelper.KeycloakSessionStateParameter, sessionId);
                            //also reset the session ID if it was previously revoked
                            var logoutSessions = context.HttpContext.RequestServices
                                .GetRequiredService<ILogoutSessionManager>();
                            logoutSessions.Remove(null, sessionId);
                        }

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    //OnTokenValidated = 
                    OnTokenResponseReceived = context =>
                    {
                        var tokenSource =
                            context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenSourceHelper>();
                        tokenSource.SetTokens(context.TokenEndpointResponse.AccessToken,
                            context.TokenEndpointResponse.RefreshToken, context.TokenEndpointResponse.IdToken);
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnTicketReceived = async context =>
                    {
                        var tokenSource =
                            context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenSourceHelper>();
                        var accessToken = await tokenSource.GetToken();
                        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                        var jwtSecurityToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(accessToken);
                        
                        //reduce the ticket size: shorten claims length
                        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal?.Identity;
                        var roles = jwtSecurityToken.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == identity.RoleClaimType);
                        identity.AddClaims(roles);

                    },
                    OnRemoteFailure = context =>
                    {
                        //no need to log the exception, it is logged by Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Home");
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = async context =>
                    {
                        if(context.Properties.Items.ContainsKey(WebTime.Business.DTO.Common.Core.Enums.GeneralConstants.TokenHintKey))
                        {
                            var idToken =
                                context.Properties.Items[
                                    GeneralConstants.TokenHintKey];
                            context.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idToken;
                        }
                        await Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            })
```

As you can see I force reading roles from **access_token** and now it works correctly, but I have too long headers because my cookies have 5 chunks.

Maybe there is another setup that helps real role claims from **access_token**?
And why it reads roles from **id_token**?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keycloak send roles with "roles" claim type name and by default asp.net core identity does not expects this name, I used `options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;` with adding unique mapping: `options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, "roles");` and then parsed array of roles that was presented as array of string

Answer (score 0):

Your client that is using AddOpenIdConnect, should not need to peek/look inside the access token.

The client should only be concerned with the id token and if you want to reduce the size of your session cookie, then you can set the AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken=false in IdentityServer. Then, as you have already set options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true; then the AddOpenIdConnect handler will get the remaining user details from the UserInfo endpoint.

Comment: Please read my question more properly: 1) **For .net client, our keycloak admins created new client scope - csharp-roles that converts roles to convenient view for .net and has setting that includes role claims to id_token. We disabled this setting because sign-out url is too large (id_token contained role claims) and sign-out works perfectly** 2)`options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;`

Comment: I was answering based on what you wrote "As you can see I force reading roles from access_token and now it works correctly"., clients are not supposed to read the access token, just pass it along. Usually, you can get the same info form the UserInfo endpoint or the Id-token. It is supposed to read the roles in the client from the ID-token , not the access token. most of the time when claims are not properly read, then you need to do some claims mapping, as the names microsoft expects is not the same as what most identity providers provides.